# Landing page canvas/logo overlay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a logo in a folder that I need to overlay over the matrix canvas/background. The bottom snippet is the logo PNG file with location. It just does not seem to come up. I have added the image with a border at 0, but it leaves a black empty block across the top. I need the image to overlap the matrix code in the center of the page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
        <title>CybernetiX Corp</title>
        <style>

            /*basic reset */
            *{
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
            }
            
            /* Page settings */
            html {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 0%, #aaa 100%) no-repeat;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            body {
                text-align: center;
                display: table;
                background: black;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                overflow-x: hidden;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }

            canvas {display:block;}
            
            #author {
                position: absolute;
                bottom: 10px;
                left: 10px;
                color : #0F0;
                z-index : 1;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }
        
            span {
                font-family: monospace;
                font-size: 1.5em;
            }
            span:after {
                content:"CybernetiX-S3C";
                opacity: 0;
                animation: cursor 1s infinite;
            }
            @keyframes cursor {
                0% {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                40% {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
                50% {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                90% {
                    opacity: 1;
                }
                100% {
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            }
        
        </style>
    </head>
    <img src="img/LOGO.png"  alt="CybernetiX-Corp">

    <body>
    
        <canvas id="c"></canvas>
        <span id = "author">John Modica @ </span>
        

        
    <script>
        // geting canvas by id c
        var c = document.getElementById("c");
        var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

        //making the canvas full screen
        c.height = window.innerHeight;
        c.width = window.innerWidth;

        //chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
        var matrix = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789@#$%^&*()*&^%";
        //converting the string into an array of single characters
        matrix = matrix.split("");

        var font_size = 10;
        var columns = c.width / font_size; //number of columns for the rain
        //an array of drops - one per column
        var drops = [];
        //x below is the x coordinate
        //1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
        for(var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
            drops[x] = 1; 

        //drawing the characters
        function draw()
        {
            //Black BG for the canvas
            //translucent BG to show trail
            ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)";
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

            ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0"; //green text
            ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
            //looping over drops
            for( var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++ )
            {
                //a random chinese character to print
                var text = matrix[ Math.floor( Math.random() * matrix.length ) ];
                //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
                ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);

                //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
                //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
                if( drops[i] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975 )
                    drops[i] = 0;

                //incrementing Y coordinate
                drops[i]++;
            }
        }

        setInterval( draw, 35 );

       </script>
    <p style-"text-align:center;"><img src="img/LOGO.png" alt="CybernetiX Corp"></p>
    </body>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

```html
    <img src="img/LOGO.png"  alt="CybernetiX-Corp">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you can do it. The main changes are.

Add the following HTML to the body. The wrapper around the image will be full-screen so you can align the image in the middle of it using css `flex`.

```
<div class="img-wrapper"><img src="your-image"></div>
```

The following CSS aligns the image in the middle of the wrapper.

```
.img-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```css
.img-wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <title>CybernetiX Corp</title>
  <style>
    /*basic reset */
    
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* Page settings */
    
    html {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background: radial-gradient(circle, #fff 0%, #aaa 100%) no-repeat;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    body {
      text-align: center;
      display: table;
      background: black;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow-x: hidden;
      overflow-y: hidden;
    }
    
    canvas {
      display: block;
    }
    
    #author {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      color: #0F0;
      z-index: 1;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }
    
    span {
      font-family: monospace;
      font-size: 1.5em;
    }
    
    span:after {
      content: "CybernetiX-S3C";
      opacity: 0;
      animation: cursor 1s infinite;
    }
    
    @keyframes cursor {
      0% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      40% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
      50% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      90% {
        opacity: 1;
      }
      100% {
        opacity: 0;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="c"></canvas>
  <span id="author">John Modica @ </span>



  <script>
    // geting canvas by id c
    var c = document.getElementById("c");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

    //making the canvas full screen
    c.height = window.innerHeight;
    c.width = window.innerWidth;

    //chinese characters - taken from the unicode charset
    var matrix = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ123456789@#$%^&*()*&^%";
    //converting the string into an array of single characters
    matrix = matrix.split("");

    var font_size = 10;
    var columns = c.width / font_size; //number of columns for the rain
    //an array of drops - one per column
    var drops = [];
    //x below is the x coordinate
    //1 = y co-ordinate of the drop(same for every drop initially)
    for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++)
      drops[x] = 1;

    //drawing the characters
    function draw() {
      //Black BG for the canvas
      //translucent BG to show trail
      ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.04)";
      ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

      ctx.fillStyle = "#0F0"; //green text
      ctx.font = font_size + "px arial";
      //looping over drops
      for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
        //a random chinese character to print
        var text = matrix[Math.floor(Math.random() * matrix.length)];
        //x = i*font_size, y = value of drops[i]*font_size
        ctx.fillText(text, i * font_size, drops[i] * font_size);

        //sending the drop back to the top randomly after it has crossed the screen
        //adding a randomness to the reset to make the drops scattered on the Y axis
        if (drops[i] * font_size > c.height && Math.random() > 0.975)
          drops[i] = 0;

        //incrementing Y coordinate
        drops[i]++;
      }
    }

    setInterval(draw, 35);
  </script>
  <div class="img-wrapper"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSYygrZgIU_1WjY1yAai9pp1hc56sm9bxMDa9aFOb5zyo5iA7mq" alt="CybernetiX Corp"></div>



</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Right. Thanks, but I need to figure out with a transparent image. How can I keep the original Transparency?

Comment: Good point, let me see what that is happening. Have you tried anything yourself already?

Comment: I have tried many different combinations of things. 3 weeks of brain farts.

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand you correctly, the broken image which in your example is showing at the top of the screen, that should be aligned in the middle of the screen but then being transpartent. Is that correct?

Comment: Originally nothing showed. I added another HTML attribute on the image snippet with the border at a 0 which then added at the very top. This also added an entire border with the image across entire top, while starting the fall down code just under that border. I then removed the border attribute, and I'm back to where the image still will not show at all.

Comment: Should I go ahead and rid of the image file and folder and just upload to a website such as ImgBB.com, or something to that effect?

Comment: OK, I have figured out my issue. My logo file was corrupted. GEEZ! ... lmao...   Thanks for the help.

Comment: Ow, glad that was the issue. That's awesome. I was alternatively looking into using two canvas items and stacking those, you can read about it [here](https://html5.litten.com/using-multiple-html5-canvases-as-layers). But it looks like this worked out well too. Great animation through! :)

Comment: Awesome, and thanks. I will definitely check that out. By the way, I noticed the image wrapper did stretch the image. Is there a way to adjust it a bit smaller so its isn't blurry?

Comment: The image wrapper uses CSS flexbox. Look it up and the properties that come with it.  It's quite useful. [This article on CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox) was useful to get my head around it. You can also set a fixed width/height to the image.